# C-Motif code project porting from unix to linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, motif

I am porting C-Motif code project from unix to ubuntu linux system.

I'm able to solve various problems but still there are some problems while doing make.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnls
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../bin/ipsge] Error 1
```

Comment: 4 libraries are not found by the linker. What is the exact OS name and version of the UNIX you're porting from?

Answer (score 3):

For -lXmu install:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-headers

sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev
```

Try compiling without `-lnls` / `-lsocket`
and see if the problem is fixed.

I don't know libl.a  What flavor of UNIX are you porting from?

Comment: `-ll` is probably a support library for lex, so `-lfl` would be the equivalent if flex was used.

Comment: Not sure why Motif should need flex. Anyway I'd try compiling without -ll to see what happens. It's probably a remnant from the original Makefile and can safely be dropped just like the socket stuff (contained in C library).

Comment: Either remnant of standard Makefiles or needed for other dependencies than Motif. (IIRC, socket and nls were needed on Solaris for things which are part of libc on linux)